# Confusing think with python

Tags: python

I cant open my code I dont know why, I reinstalled my windows and after that I installed python and doesnt work anymore. Can you help me please ?

```
Users\merisinho\Desktop\School>game.py
ile "C:\Users\merisinho\Desktop\School\game.py", line 10
taxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file C:\Users\merisinho\Desktop\School\game.py on line 11, but no encoding declared;
```

see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

Answer (score 2):

Try putting this at the top of your `game.py` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

Also I suggest reading the link they provide in the error to understand why you need that (or might need another encoding).